# matplotlib - Getting rid of white spots in hexbin

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a heatmap using the `maxplotlib` `hexbin` function, but I somehow get some regularly placed white spots on the plot, as shown below:
[image: whie spots on the hexbin plot]

I essentially have a function [image: f:R^2->R] that evaluates to a real, and then I follow the typical steps for `hexbin` (I am always sure that the problem is not with the `f` function).

My code is shown below. Any insight would be appreciated..

```
# Values for the axes
x = y = np.linspace(-400,1000,100) 
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z_s = np.zeros((len(x),len(y)))
z_j = np.zeros((len(x),len(y)))

# Generate the values using the `f` function
for i_ax, ax in enumerate(x):
    for i_ay, ay in enumerate(y):
        z_s[i_ax, i_ay] = f(ax, ay)
# Plot
Xr = X.ravel()
Yr = Y.ravel()
Zr_s = z_s.ravel()

fig = plt.figure()
plt.hexbin(Xr, Yr, C = Zr_s)
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't due to insufficient density of calculated points?  Have you tried increasing the number of points in your `linspace` from 100 to 500 or 1000?

Comment: Without you providing a runable program that reproduces the error, we can merely speculate what the problem could be.

Comment: Why are you using hexbin to display values on a rectangular grid?    Why not use `imshow` or `pcolormesh`?  What's happening is that values on a square grid fall such that some hexagonal bins will always wind up empty.  You can fit more hexagons in an area than squares. Hexbin is intended for binning (i.e. spatially aggregating) values, not for displaying values directly.